# robot_localization odom wrong frame

Tags: navigation, odometry, transform, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm having an issue with robot_localization when my sensor frames are offset from the base_link frame.

I have robot with a realsense T265 odometry sensor, but when I run a robot_localization UKF, it places the robot frame at the odometry message instead of the sensor frame.

TF tree:

```
odom        base_link -> base_link/t265
```

Topic:

```
name: /base_link/t265/odom
type: Odometry
frame_id: odom
child_frame_id: base_link/t265
```

UKF Config:

```
map_frame: map
odom_frame: odom
base_link_frame: base_link
world_frame: odom

odom0: /base_link/t265/odom
```

Below I have the Odometry topic and the TF tree after the UKF is run.

**Issue:** Since the odom's `child_frame_id` is `base_link/t265`, the odom topic should identify the location of that frame, not the `base_link` frame, right? I’m expecting the UKF to compute the `odom->base_link` tf such that the t265 frame will be placed at its odom message, but instead it places base_link there directly.

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/344889/robot_localization-odom-wrong-frame/) by [jnoyola](https://answers.ros.org/users/52031/jnoyola/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-02-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-02-24**:
Please attach your screenshot to the question. I've given you sufficient karma.

**Comment by [jnoyola](https://answers.ros.org/users/52031/jnoyola/) on 2020-02-24**:
Thank you. Updated the question with the screenshot.

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2020-02-24**:
What's your issue exactly? Its unclear to me.

**Comment by [jnoyola](https://answers.ros.org/users/52031/jnoyola/) on 2020-02-24**:
Updated the last sentence. Hopefully that clarifies it. This sounds like a standard use case that I’ve seen lots of discussion about, but no end to end examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I went with the manual solution, manually calculating where the odom message should be for the robot frame instead of the sensor frame.

This problem is also described in the last comment on the accepted answer [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/239326/sensor-frame-offset-for-robot_localization-absolute-odometer-offset/?answer=239409#post-id-239409), which also suggests it must be done manually.

To do this, I post-multiply the odom message's pose by the `sensor-to-base_link` transform. Then, in order to make the base_link appear to start at 0 instead of the sensor, I pre-multiply this by the `base_link-to-sensor` transform. Thus if your `base_link-to-sensor` (or sensor mount pose) transform is `S`, I compute

```
odom_msg.pose.pose = S * odom_msg.pose.pose * S.inverse()
```

This assumes your twists (linear and angular) are already rotated by the pose's rotation after this calculation.
Also note it's more performant to precompute `S.inverse()` rather than recalculating this every frame.

---

Originally posted by [jnoyola](https://answers.ros.org/users/52031/jnoyola/) with karma: 1 on 2020-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: -2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jnoyola](https://answers.ros.org/users/52031/jnoyola/) on 2020-03-03**:
Not sure why there are downvotes. It looks like this has been an issue for several years, and Steve's answer only works for putting *all* of the fused data in the T265 frame, which is not what I want. Please share a better solution if you have one.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2020-03-03**:
@jnoyola Please consider your tone and expectations when you're writing your responses. People on this forum are volunteering their time to help answer questions. It's not our responsibility to solve your problem. https://wiki.ros.org/Support You will find that if you become confrontational people will choose to help others.

You've accepted your own answer to the question but reading your question the other answer appears to be a better solution. I think that your use case has more details than your explaining, that external reviewers do not understand due to a partial problem statement. This especially rings true to me as your statement that you don't want "all" the fused data in the same frame, as that seems to be the opposite of computing a fused result.

**Comment by [jnoyola](https://answers.ros.org/users/52031/jnoyola/) on 2020-03-03**:
I apologize if that came across as confrontational. I was just asking an honest question, because my solution solved my problem but received downvotes, suggesting people believe there is a better solution. In the comments on the other solution, I have tried explaining in 3 different ways why that does not appear to solve the problem, but received no response.

In response to your point here, I did not say that I don't want all the fused data in the same frame -- I simply don't want all the fused data in the T265 frame. The problem I have been trying to solve is where I have sensor A readings giving me `odom-to-A` and sensor B readings giving me `odom-to-B` and want to output `odom-to-base_link`. The other solution suggests I can use the T265 frame, but it seems like r_l will then interpret all sensors as providing `odom-to-T265`, which does not solve the problem. Please correct me if I'm misunderstanding.